# R find nearest neighbor for selected point

Tags: r, knn

I have a csv file with only 20 datapoints, and I'd like to know the nearest neighbor for a new data point.

My csv file looks like this

```
temp    rain
79        12
81        13 
79        4
61        9
60        15
45        5
34        5
100       9
101       3
59        11
58        16
```

So I would like to know the proper way to find the nearest neighbor for the point 65, 7 using the euclidean distance and KNN. Most of the algorithms available online are using large datasets such as iris or german from R, but this is so small it does not require cleaning, so I feel as though those solutions are over-complicating this problem. I am still very new to R so I may have overlooked a solution. Thank you for taking the time to read this!

I have tried the following code but it keeps throwing an error, again I think I am just over-complicating this

```
df <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ',')

head(df) 

ran <- sample(1:nrow(df), 0.9 * nrow(df)) 

nor <-function(x) { (x -min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))   }

df_train <- df[ran,] 

df_test <- df[-ran,] 
##extract 5th column of train dataset because it will be used as 'cl' argument in knn function.
df_target_category <- df[ran,2]
##extract 5th column if test dataset to measure the accuracy
df_test_category <- df[-ran,2]

library(class)

pr <- knn(df_train,df_test,cl=df_target_category,k=13)

##create confusion matrix
tab <- table(pr,df_test_category)

accuracy <- function(x){sum(diag(x)/(sum(rowSums(x)))) * 100}
accuracy(tab)
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: If you have not tried any code or are not getting any errors in the code you have, then I suggest this is more of a mathematical/statistical question, in which case it is more appropriate on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). If you are having problems with code you have already tried, please provide that code and any errors/warnings or incorrect results you get.

Comment: @r2evans I have updated my question with your suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think base R is sufficient to calculate the euclidean distance, i.e.,

```
distance <- sqrt(rowSums((df-do.call(rbind,replicate(nrow(df),p,simplify = FALSE)))**2))
nearest <- df[which.min(distance),]
```

such that

```
> nearest
  temp rain
4   61    9
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(temp = c(79L, 81L, 79L, 61L, 60L, 45L, 34L, 100L, 
101L, 59L, 58L), rain = c(12L, 13L, 4L, 9L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 
3L, 11L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

p <- structure(list(temp = 65, rain = 7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your question is related to KNN. Why not simply calculate the Euclidean distance of the new point to all other points in `df`, and then determine which point in `df` is closest? To do so, we can use use R's `dist` which returns a (by default: Euclidean) distance matrix.

Here is a minimal example in two steps, based on the sample you give.

```r
# Calculate Euclidean distances of `pt` to all points in `df`
dist_to_pt <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(df, pt)))[nrow(df) + 1, 1:nrow(df)]

# Determine the point in `df` with minimal distance to `pt`
dist_to_pt[which.min(dist_to_pt)]
#       4
#4.472136
```

So point 4 in `df` is the nearest neighbour to the new point at (65, 7).

We can visualise old and new data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
rbind(df, pt) %>%
    mutate(
        pt_number = row_number(),
        source = ifelse(pt_number > nrow(df), "new", "ref")) %>%
    ggplot(aes(temp, rain, colour = source, label = pt_number)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(position = position_nudge(y = -0.5))
```

[image]

Point 4 is the nearest neighbour of the new point 12 at (65, 7).

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
    "temp    rain
79        12
81        13
79        4
61        9
60        15
45        5
34        5
100       9
101       3
59        11
58        16", header = T)

# New point
pt <- c(temp = 65, rain = 7)
```